# How to open specific page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to open my webiste post with specific id, but when I go to this link which is first post page `http://localhost:8000/tickets/create/1` its opening correct id (1 is id) but tells me that "404 not found".

There are my codes.

**Controller**

```
public function create()
    {
        $ticketsinfos = Tickets::with('companies')->get();
        $tickets = Companies::with('tickets')->get();
        $severities = Severities::with('severity')->get();
        $ticketscounts = Tickets::count();
        //return view('dashboard.index',['ticketscounts'=> $ticketscounts]);
        $users = DB::table('tickets')->get();
      
        return view('customer.index')->with(['tickets'=> $tickets])->with(['severities' => $severities])->with(['ticketsinfos' => $ticketsinfos])->with(['ticketscounts'=> $ticketscounts])->with(['users'=>$users]);
      
         //dd($users->toArray());
    }
```

**Blade.php**

```
 <tr>
    @foreach ($ticketsinfos as $ticketinfo)
        <td>IR-173049</td>
        <td>Tudro</td> 
        <td>{{ $ticketinfo->companies->name }}</td>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <td><a href="tickets/create/{{ $user->id }}">{{ Str::limit($ticketinfo->ticket_title, 50, '...') }}</a></td>
        @endforeach
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">Action Needed<br></button><br></td>
        <td>Tako Kiknadze</td>
        <td>{{ $ticketinfo->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $ticketinfo->updated_at }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach    
</tr>
```

My route:

```
Route::resource('/tickets', TicketsController::class);
```

What can I do for do this?

Comment: What's your route?

Comment: Route::resource('/tickets', TicketsController::class);

Comment: (Unrelated) Something looks off with two `</tr>`s

Comment: hello bromber , which information need you?

Comment: "_/tickets/create/1 its opening correct id(1 is id)_" The `create` route should not take any parameter, it should be the form to _create_ a new ticket. There are the [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller).

Comment: Nevermind, I added your route to your question

Comment: What can I do for It ? What I do to open my post by id, like this website  when you click my post opened my post if you click another for example tom post you will open tom post I want same thing on my website

Comment: It's either `/tickets/create` to create a new ticket or `/tickets/1/edit` to edit an existing ticket. Did you read the link I posted? An "easier" way would be to _not_ hardcode URLs but use the named routes instead

Comment: Do I do it with edit function?

Comment: If you're asking if you use the `edit` method to edit an existing ticket: yes.

Comment: Is better to use  routes like this? Route::get('business/list', 'BusinessController@viewBusiness')->name('viewBusiness');

Comment: "better" in what sense? That's a completely different route, not sure why you'd want to use that. [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) has all the actions of a Resource Controller. [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) shows how to generate links to named routes. You can use `php artisan route:list` to get a list of your routes along with their names

Comment: This route I used for example

Comment: I imply that is better to use route like this format "Route::get()" then  thisRoute::resource am I correct?

Comment: Not really. A resource route has _all_ the routes you need for CRUD. You can however add all the routes needed manually, `Route::resource` is a convenience method so you don't have to type all routes by hand. This site isn't really to teach you the basics, that's what the manual or tutorials are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think part of the issue is that the URL you are trying to go to is incorrect. You specified it was a Route::Resource.  This is a shortcut in writing routes.  What this does is create a list of routes as can be seen by a `artisan route:list`.

The `Route::resource('/tickets', TicketsController::class);` line in web.php creates specific routes and points to  the specific methods in that class.

The specific methods are:

```
 - index : Display a listing of the resource.
 - create : Show the form for creating a new resource.
 - store : Store a newly created resource in storage.
 - show : Display the specified resource.
 - edit : Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 - update : Update the specified resource in storage.
 - destroy : Remove the specified resource from storage.
```

Personally, I like to use the artisan command `artisan make:model --all` or `artisan make:model --resource`. I would suggest that you use a `artisan make:controller --resource Bogus` and then see how it affects your routes. The default comments clearly spell out how each route is used and the parameters that it is expecting.

@Bromerbeer I think was giving you the correct info.  The "Create" route takes no parameters and does not accept any.  From how you worded the question, it seems you would want
http://localhost:8000/tickets/**show**/1

Then it will accept an 'id' parameter (in this case a model) :

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\BogusModel  $bogus
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(BogusModel $bogus)
{
    //
}
```

Where as the "create" method takes no parameters:

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score -2):

there is a problem with your route

try updating your route to be like this:

```
Route::resource('tickets/create/{id}', TicketsController::class);
```

and update your function like this:

```
public function create($id)
{
    $ticketsinfos = Tickets::with('companies')->get();
    $tickets = Companies::with('tickets')->get();
    $severities = Severities::with('severity')->get();
    $ticketscounts = Tickets::count();
    //return view('dashboard.index',['ticketscounts'=> $ticketscounts]);
    $users = DB::table('tickets')->where('id',$id)->get();
  
    return view('customer.index')->with(['tickets'=> $tickets])->with(['severities' => $severities])->with(['ticketsinfos' => $ticketsinfos])->with(['ticketscounts'=> $ticketscounts])->with(['users'=>$users]);
  
     //dd($users->toArray());
}
```

Comment: That's a _resource_ route - no parameters required

Comment: if you want to access the address http://localhost:8000/tickets/create/1 then you need to create a route as I explained. If not then the response will not be found

Comment: Have you tried my answer so you say what I did wrong ?